# Using unix (awk, sed, bash?) to truncate items in a column by the 4th underscore?

Tags: bash, awk, text, sed

I have series of files that look like this, the second and third column are duplicates but with thousands of lines.

```
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 6.26e-66
```

I want to take the 3rd column and truncate it so that everything in the string after and including _i is deleted, like so:

```
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 6.26e-66
```

The numbers after each letter combination (DN, c, g, i, p) could be anything and could also be any length, so I can't just truncate to a certain length.

I've tried `sed -i 's/_i.*//' file.txt` But this deleted everything after each line and not just the column of interest.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/_[^_]+$/,"",$3)}1' file

AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 6.26e-66
```

in 3rd field delete everything after the last underscore (including).

Answer (score 2):

You can remove from the first occurrence of `_i` followed by the rest of the line in the third field using awk:

```
awk 'sub(/_i.*/, "", $3)1' file
```

Output

```
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 6.26e-66
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer; if your Trinity contigs don't necessarily have an isoform associated with them (i.e. there is no "_i.*") this won't mangle the output. @HatLess's solution also handles this 'edge case'. In future, check out https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ for this type of domain-specific question. Also, you are strongly encouraged to include your own attempts to solve the problem when posting questions to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/\(g[0-9]*\)_[^ ]*/\1/2' input_file
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 6.26e-66
```

You can carry out the substitution on the second occurrence of the match

Answer (score 0):

This will do it using GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*_i.*\)_i.*\(\s.*\)/\1\2/' your_file > output_file
```

- `\(` and `\)` are capture groups, that remember the matched stuff inside
- `\(.*_i.*\)_i.*` remembers everything up to (but not including) the second `_i`
- `\(\s.*\)` remembers everything from the space after the second `_i` to the end of the line
- `/\1\2/` replaces the line with the first and second capture group (i.e. dropping out everything from the second `_i` up to the first space after that.

Outputs

```
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g2 1.36e-115
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i2.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 9.97e-113
AT1G15820.1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1_i1.p1 TRINITY_DN96909_c1_g1 6.26e-66
```

Answer (score 0):

a perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -lane '$F[2] = join "_", (split /_/, $F[2])[0..3]; print "@F"' file
```

That splits the 3rd field on underscore, takes the first 4 components and joins them with underscore.